# Uploading an image with php/ajax is refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, form-data

The script is working fine, I'm using `formData()`for uploading the image with ajax, and it is correctly being uploaded to the folder, but I can't understand why my page is being refreshed after `move_uploaded_file()` gets called in the php script. 

This is the full code:

**index.html**

```
<label>Add picture?</label>
<input type='file' accept='.png,.gif,.jpg' onchange='upload_img(this)'>
```

**script.js**

```
function upload_img(e) {
  let file = e.files[0];
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    // I want to show a message here but the page is being refreshed
    document.getElementById('ajax_result').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }
  xhr.open("POST", "upload_img.php", true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

**upload_img.php**

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
    var_dump($_FILES['file']);
    $path = "../img_uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file " .  basename($_FILES['file']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**
For testing purposes I deleted all forms in the page and the issue is still there.

Comment: you dont have submit buttons or form tags or anything like that?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I have a form in the page but this input is outside of it.

Comment: u probably have `form action=""` in form tags

Comment: I want to prevent `move_uploaded_file()` from actually submitting anything. Are there some methods to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try first xfr.open then xfr.onload